# How to make a styled DataGridCheckBoxColumn to respect DataGrid.IsReadonly?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid.IsReadonly` bound to a property that changes based on a condition.  The `DataGrid` contains a `DataGridCheckBox` column that I had to style in order to center it vertically in a cell.

However, after applying a style the check box column does not respect the parent's `IsReadonly` value.  That is, regardless of its value the `checkbox` can be clicked on and changed. I've seen quite a number of posts dealing with somewhat similar situations but could not find a reliable solution.

Could someone please let me know how to style the checkbox column so it respects its parent griddata's IsReadonly?  Any theory behind it would also be appreciated.

This how I apply the style:

```
<Style x:Key="CenterStyleCB" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ...  ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterStyleCB}" />
```

Comment: post a minimal amount of code

Comment: yes.. post the style you applied to checkboxcolumn

Comment: Sample code inserted into my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your style:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Column.IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

If your DataGrid is always ReadOnly, then I would suggest you skip the trigger and use the setter directly.